# How to reinit a owl carousel 2.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I know in the first version of owl carousel we do it like this :

```
var $carousel = $('#carousel');
var owl = $carousel.data('owlCarousel'); 
owl.reinit({touchDrag: false, mouseDrag: false;});
```

Ok, but how we do it in the second version, i don't know how they renamed it.

Comment: What do you mean by *it*? BTW, did you check the docs of new version??

Comment: @TJ Even when he did. The docs are outdated currently because I haven't the time to update them currently.

Answer (score 22):

For some reasons **$('#your_carousel').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel')** is not working correctly. it does not remove all classes which are needed to reinit the plugin again.

You'll need to remove them completely to destroy the "owl carousel 2". like described here in this issue on github: https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/issues/460

To destroy the owl function use:

```
$('#your_carousel').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel').removeClass('owl-carousel owl-loaded');
$('#your_carousel').find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();
```

This worked perfect for me:

```
// find element
$owl = $('body').find('#your_carousel');

// set the owl-carousel otions
var carousel_Settings = {
  touchDrag: false,
  mouseDrag: false
};

function initialize(){
  var containerWidth = $('body').find('.navbar').outerWidth();
  if(containerWidth <= 767) {
    // initialize owl-carousel if window screensize is less the 767px
    $owl.owlCarousel( carousel_Settings );
  } else {
    // destroy owl-carousel and remove all depending classes if window screensize is bigger then 767px
    $owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel').removeClass('owl-carousel owl-loaded');
    $owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();
  }
}

// initilize after window resize
var id;
$(window).resize( function() {
  clearTimeout(id);
  id = setTimeout(initialize, 500);
});

// initilize onload
initialize();
```

Comment: Not Working @Daniel

Answer (score 17):

You can do that with `destroy` but you have to use latest [`develop` branch](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2/archive/develop.zip):

```
$('#carousel').owlCarousel('destroy'); 
$('#carousel').owlCarousel({touchDrag: false, mouseDrag: false});
```

Or with direct access to the plugin:

```
$('#carousel').data('owl.carousel').destroy(); 
$('#carousel').owlCarousel({touchDrag: false, mouseDrag: false});
```

Comment: Working fine for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Now, you can destroy it like that:

```
var simple = $('#simple');
simple.owlCarousel(); // created
simple.owlCarousel('destroy'); // destroyed
```

Comment: perfect !! works

Answer (score 4):

This definitly works:

```
if (container.hasClass("owl-carousel")) {
    container.owlCarousel({
        touchDrag: false,
        mouseDrag: false
    });
    container.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    container.removeClass('owl-carousel owl-loaded');
    container.find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();
    container.removeData();
}
```

And the plugin itself:

```
if (this.settings.responsive !== false) {
                window.clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer);
                $(window).off('resize.owl.carousel');
                this.off(window, 'resize', this.e.onThrottledResize);
            }
```

in Owl.prototype.destroy = function()

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, have you tried the replace?

As per the OwlCarousel documentation, listed here http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html, the event to trigger is "**replace.owl.carousel**".  You can implement it like this :

```
var $carousel = $('#carousel');
var owl = $carousel.data('owlCarousel'); 
owl.trigger('replace.owl.carousel', [{touchDrag: false, mouseDrag: false;}]);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The url is down but I found this one to be working: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/blob/master/index.html also there's a function called owl.reinit(...) which might be of interest

Comment: As of 2017-08-24 the other link doesn't work either.

Comment: you have syntax problem

Answer (score 0):

If use v1.3 I make next

```
$('#OwlWrapper').owlCarousel({option...});
$('#OwlWrapper').append('<div><img class="img-fluid" src="demo_files/images/1200x800/5-min.jpg" alt=""></div>');
$('#OwlWrapper').data('owlCarousel').reinit();
```

It's work for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have answered a very old question. Please make sure your answer is relevant to the question and adds something that the other answers doesn't provide. You should see [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> $('#your_carousel').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel').removeClass('owl-carousel
>   owl-loaded');
>   $('#your_carousel').find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();

Just do this to destroy the owl carousel and then use the general init function to reinit.

Answer (score 0):

For **Owl Carousel v2.3.4** version,

```
// Slider element.
let sliderElement = $('#msg-slider');

// Destroy first.
sliderElement.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');

// Then empty whole owl div.
sliderElement.empty();

// Re-init owl slider.
sliderElement
    .owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:0,
        nav:false,
        dots:true,
        responsive:{
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items:1
            },
            1000: {
                items:1
            }
        }
});
```

Hopefully, this will help someone. Thanks.